# set the pageContent in node-slimerJS or for slimerJS globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, automated-tests, slimerjs

I'm trying to set the network [capture content](https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/webpage.html#webpage-capturecontent)  using [node-slimerjs](https://github.com/MangoTools/node-slimerjs)  bridge for node js. What I would do using plain slimerJS is the following:

```
page.captureContent = [/html/, /text/];
```

but I have to use the getter setter functions in the node-slimerjs library so using the these functions I'm using the following code:

```
page.set('captureContent',[/text/,/html/]);
```

but the setter function isn't setting the value correctly and I'm left with the empty body for the network responses with text/* and html/* types. 
After setting the captureContent if I try to read the value with console.log I can see that only an empty object has been set to the capture content:

```
page.get('captureContent', function(err,val){
        console.log('captureContent::: ',val)
        });
```

from node console:

> *captureContent::: [ {}, {} ]*

I also tried creating new regex objects and setting them using the setter function but got the same result.

```
var re = new RegExp("html");
var re2 = new RegExp("text");
```

In the [SlimerJS documentation](https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/webpage.html#webpage-capturecontent) it is stated that by default this is limited to avoid memory problems. So it may be possible to unlimit this so...
How can I set the pageContent in slimerJS either globally or from node-slimerJS library so I can see the network body for responses with certain content types?

Comment: The regexes probably need to be serialized before sending it to the slimerjs process from the node-bridge, but the script on the other side probably doesn't know how it can be deserialized. Can you use plain strings?

Comment: the reason you've described sounds logical but unfortunately using plain strings didn't do the job. I mean I tried 'text/plain' since I want the body for plain text responses but didn't work. I also tried the regex in a string.